How to Extend Session Expiration Time in Google BigQuery Storage API for Long-Running Data Reads in Python
I am using the Google BigQuery Storage API (Python library) to fetch large datasets from BigQuery and write them to a third-party system. Due to the large volume of data, I'm currently encountering a session expiration error after 6 hours of reading data.
Could you help me with configuration information to increase the expiration time of the data reading session through the "BigQuery Storage API"?
Current session configuration I am using:
python
Create the read session with a reduced number of streams to avoid overloading
    session = self.client.create_read_session(
        parent=parent,
        read_session=requested_session,
        timeout=86400,  # Set timeout to 24 hours
        max_stream_count=200
    )

Error Message:
400 there was an error operating on 'projects/your-project/locations/us/sessions/CAISDEFtMGpQVTRqYmxvdRoCamQaAmpm/streams/CDAaAmpkGgJqZigC': session expired at 2024-11-04T10:53:31+00:00
